# Searching for values with formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I need to make a list of which student is taking what kind of exam on which date and time.

The sheet with all the data looks like this:

[image: https://imgshare.io/images/2019/05/17/helpspreadsheet.jpg]

This is per student but not per date.

I would like to have a tab per exam AND time. So exam Dutch is taken at 06-06-2019 at 10:00h, 12:00h and 14:00h. Tabs should be like: tab1 all students that take exam Dutch at 06-06-2019 10h, tab2 all students that take exam Dutch at 06-06-2019 12h, etc.

The order of columns can't change because the sheet as in the example is also generated with formulas etc. from other sheets.

I tried the `VLOOKUP` formula but this can't search on the left. I have absolutely no idea how to solve this.

I'm not looking for a ready to use answer. Just push me in the right direction.

Comment: @player0 The solution JPV posted works perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use filter() or query().
Assuming 'achternaam' in column A and 'exam Dutch' is in column E, you can try

```
=query('SheetwithData'!A:E, "Select A where E contains '06-06-2019 10:00'", 1)
```

Replace the sheet name with the actual sheet name.